# Using ArcGIS Field Calculator and Python Parser to add zeros and ones?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a lot of rows of data, and I want to use the field calculator to give a uniform assignment of

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
...
```

but I don't know how to implement it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You could look at the Python modulo operator of %

Comment: @Polygeo it will always work on shapefile (FID), not necessarily on features in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this advanced field calculator expression (Python):

```
i=0
def switch():
 global i
 i=1-i
 return i
*-------
switch()
```

Answer (score 3):

As @PolyGeo mentioned, the modulo operator helps you determine whether a number is pair or not. You can check the "Show Codeblock" box in the field calculator and then write a simple function that determines wheter the row is pair or not and adds a 0 or a 1 depending on the condition

```
def calc(fid):
    if fid % 2 != 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Then, in the box under you jsut have to call the function using the FID field as an argument.

`calc( !FID! )`

Note: make sure python is checked as the parser.

Comment: Why bother with advanced expression if simple !FID!%2 solves it for shapefile?

Comment: I understand this idea, but I use it  to achieve, there will be mistakes.I  use the previous method can be achieved.